# Rubygems-style utility for .NET?

Tags: .net, rubygems

Is there anything like Ruby gems for .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horn is a promising new project that should do what is needed.
http://code.google.com/p/hornget/

Answer (score 1):

There is a new project called Nu which uses the actual Ruby gems framework to package .NET components. http://groups.google.com/group/nu-net

Comment: I've created an add-in for Visual Studio that make it easy to reference gems in your project.
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ba0f6da5-3660-4983-b8fb-d5abfc45093e

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which characteristics of Ruby Gems you are looking for. If you are trying to deploy your own application, you should look into [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx).

Comment: I want an easy way to bring in common tools/libraries into a project.